# jQuery replace Vimeo embed with fade in and fade out

Tags: jquery, api, fadein, fadeout, vimeo

I'd like to fade a Vimeo universal embed (iframe version) out, pause it, fade in another one, and autoplay it. My code fades out and pauses the first video, but immediately brings in the new one (without the fade) and then doesn't auto play it. I'm guessing it's a syntax issue. I'm using the froogaloop js library to control the Vimeo API.

Ideas? Thanks for your help!

HTML:

```
    <div id="fire" class="vim">
        <iframe id="regular" class="vid" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/22327264?api=1&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff"></iframe>
        <iframe id="behind" class="vid" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/22466069?api=1&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff"></iframe>
        <p style="float:left">
            "Sound of Fire"<br />
            This Century<br />
            Warner Brothers Records
        </p>
        <p id="bts" style="float:right;color:#000000;cursor:pointer;">
            &nbsp;<br />
            Click to launch the "Sound of Fire" behind the scenes video!<br />
            &nbsp;
        </p>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $('#behind').hide();
    $('#bts').click(function() {
        $('#regular').fadeOut(400);
        var player=$f($('.vid:visible')[0]);
        player.api('pause');
        $('#behind').fadeIn(400);
        player.api('play');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` do not block further code execution while the animation runs. This means, as you're seeing, that the player is paused as soon as the fade out begins, and immediately after that, the fade in begins, and the player is unpaused.

You need to use the (optional) callback argument if you want to use execute code when the animation is complete:

```
$('#bts').click(function() {
    $('#regular').fadeOut(400, function () {
        $f(this).api('pause');
        $('#behind').fadeIn(400, function () {
            $f(this).api('play');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Matt Ball- Great, the fade out/fade in works perfectly now. The Vimeo API pause/play, however isn't working. Any thoughts?

Comment: @techno: just edited. It's a guess, but I think it's the right guess ;-)

Comment: @Matt pauses #regular, doesn't replay behind. Can't I call them by ID?

Comment: @techno: oh, whoops! Sorry, my code calls `.api('pause')` both times - definitely a typo! Fixed. There is no need to re-select by ID when `this` is already a reference to the right element. And, c'mon, it's an excuse to write code which you can read as "F this"

Comment: @Matt i didn't notice it either.. must be late :D! Beautiful answer, thank you for your help. May I pick your brain for one other thing? I have a div called #close that fades out #fire and all of its content. Do you have a recommendation for resetting #regular and #behind when the div closes? I brought up the question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684902/jquery-reset-visible-video-when-fading-out-a-container

Comment: @Matt. $f(this).yes(); #nerdhumoratitsbest

Comment: No worries! Clearly it's late and we're both running sub-100%.

Answer (score 0):

you have define

```
var player=$f($('.vid:visible')[0]);
```

and do the action ( **pause and play** ) with same **var player**

`player.api('pause')`  `player.api('play`) `

btw what u r doing with this code

```
var player=$f($('.vid:visible')[0]);
```

#### UPDATE

I hope this will work ( raw code )

```
$('#behind').hide();
$('#bts').live('click',function() {
    $('#regular').fadeOut(400,function(){
        $f(this).api('pause');
    });
    $('#behind:hidden').fadeIn(400,function(){
        $f(this).api('play');
    });      
})
```

Note: Thanks to **@Matt Ball**

Comment: @diEcho var player=$f($('.vid:visible')[0]); defines the visible video.

Comment: `visible` video means u want to pause the video having `iframe with id=regular` m i right??

Comment: @diEcho the updated code doesn't work. #regular fades out but keeps playing. #behind never fades in.

Comment: Why the `'iframe#regular'` instead of `'#regular'`? There can be at most 1 element with any particular ID, so there's no reason to specify further.

Comment: i think `fadeIn` not works with `hidden` element..if u want to hide second iframe at page load then set `style="display:none"` inside that iframe

Comment: @Matt Ball u r right..that is more suitable..this will search only for iframe and then for id..otherwise all page is gonna search.

Comment: No, actually, jQuery selectors work by filtering from right to left (with one exception). http://forum.jquery.com/topic/about-selectors-right-to-left