# jQuery reset visible video when fading out a container

Tags: jquery, fadein, hidden, fadeout, visible

I've got a page with a container that has several videos embedded from vimeo via their new universal embed. All of the videos are each in a smaller container which has the iframe embed and a paragraph describing the video. jQuery has the smaller containers initially hidden, and dynamically selects and fades in the appropriate container depending on which thumbnail you click on. Whichever container is active can be faded out by clicking on a close-button or outside of the container (think lightbox). Of all the smaller containers that have a video, there is one that has two videos and they can be toggled between by a link below the video. When loaded, video #regular shows and clicking the link fades it out then fades #behind in.

The issue I'm running into is that if I open a video, close it, then open the same or another video the Vimeo player is hidden. The smaller container with the individual paragraph information is brought in perfectly.

The code I've written brings in one container at a time pertaining to the thumbnail you click on. I think the issue is that it explicitly hides the videos to accomodate that single video toggle.

Thanks for your help!

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="close"></div>
    <div id="tide" class="vim">
        <iframe class="vid" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/1747304?api=1&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff"></iframe>
        <p>
            "It's High Tide Baby!"<br />
            The Blackout feat. Ian Watkins (Lostprophets)<br />
            Fierce Panda
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="knew" class="vim">
        <iframe class="vid" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/4622464?api=1&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff"></iframe>
        <p>
            "If Only They Knew"<br />
            A Rocket To The Moon<br />
            Fueled by Ramen/Atlantic Records
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="fire" class="vim">
        <iframe id="regular" class="vid" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/22327264?api=1&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff"></iframe>
        <iframe id="behind" class="vid" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/22466069?api=1&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff"></iframe>
        <p style="float:left">
            "Sound of Fire"<br />
            This Century<br />
            Warner Brothers Records
        </p>
        <p id="bts" style="float:right;color:#000000;cursor:pointer;">
            &nbsp;<br />
            Click to launch the "Sound of Fire" behind the scenes video!<br />
            &nbsp;
        </p>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
//Hide containers
$('.vim, #behind, #close, #container, #underlay').hide();

//Fade in video corresponding to thumbnail
$('.thumbnail').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("show_","").toLowerCase();
    $('#' + id + ', #close, #container, #underlay').fadeIn(400);
    var player=$f($('.vid:visible')[0]);
    player.api("seekTo", "0").api('play');

});

//Toggle between videos in the #fire div
$('#bts').click(function() {
    $('#regular').fadeOut(400, function () {
        $f(this).api('pause');
        $('#behind').fadeIn(400, function () {
            $f(this).api('play');
        });
    });
});

//Close whichever video is visible
$('#close, #underlay').click(function() {
    var $videos = $('.vid');
    $f($videos.filter(':visible')[0]).api('pause');
    $videos.hide();
    $('.vim, #close, #container, #underlay').fadeOut(400, function() {
        $videos.first().show();
    });
});
```

---

```
    $('#close, #underlay').click(function() {
        var $videos = $('.vid');
        $f($videos.filter(':visible')[0]).api('pause');
        $('.vim, #close, #container, #underlay').fadeOut(400, function() {
            $('#behind').hide();
            $('#regular').show();
        });
    });
```

Comment: isn't it similar to your [previous Question](http://goo.gl/EzYjR)

Comment: @diEcho: please don't use URL shorteners. There's plenty of room in the comment for the full URL. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29518/can-and-should-stack-overflow-automatically-rewrite-bit-ly-links/29520#29520

Comment: @diEcho wasn't in my brain, was on paper. I rewrote my question with more specificity. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#close, #underlay').click(function() {
    var $videos = $('.vid');
    $f($videos.filter(':visible')[0]).api('pause');
    $videos.hide();
    $('.vim, #close, #container, #underlay').fadeOut(400, function () {
        $videos.first().show();
    });
});
```

Comment: @Matt the function I posted works perfectly- pausing the visible video and all. The issue pertains to that previous question. I'll edit the question and make it more clear. To be brief, now that the video replacement within the #fire div works (thanks to you!) i've run into another issue. when i close and reopen the #fire div, the #behind video is visible, not #regular. So i'm thinking an if/then that says IF the div closing is #fire, then reset it with #regular shown and #behind hidden. honestly, I dont have any idea of how to do this correctly, let alone efficiently.

Comment: Sorry, it's late and I should have gone to bed after answering your previous question. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: @Matt tell me about it! Clearly you have a deep understanding.. I really appreciate the help. Your edit half-works. Fades everything out appropriately, but when call #fire no video is in it at all. In my code the videos are never specifically hidden, just the containers that they're in. So #regular needs to be "shown" before the entire #fire div is hidden

Comment: @Matt forgot to mention that I understand your answer and how it theoretically solves the problem by filtering the variable and all that.. Some little hitch in it or something.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the problem is/what you're trying to get it to do. Mind putting together a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem? I started one but clearly it's missing some pieces: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/YQFS8/

Comment: I edited that fiddle a little bit more, and it seems to do exactly what you're going for...

Comment: @Matt updated it with more code from my site for context and I'm running into two issues. The fade in/autoplay function isn't calling in any videos and the whole video replace/fade out/fade back in without the original video showing. Here's the updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/YQFS8/4/
Matt, I really appreciate your help on this one. I realize it's taken far too much of your time. I'll send all the good juju and karma I can.

Answer (score 0):

Just think about what happens in your code and in what order:

1. The #fire element appears with #regular video in front.
2. Then #regular video is faded out, so now #behind is visible
3. Then #fire is faded out, so it is not visible anymore. #regular still explicitly faded out as well.
4. #fire is opened again. #regular still explicitly faded out, that's why #behind is visible.

You should add a check whether #regular is visible or not either when #fire is shown or when it is closed.

Comment: yeah, the logic makes sense. I'm struggling with a method to change the order back when the #fire div is faded out. Any ideas?